# delay fcm notification when app is killed

Tags: flutter

i have a problem when i kill app and reopen in flutter. the message that i received when app was terminated, i receive it after 2 minutes when app is running and not immediately when app is opened. why? that's my code:

```
void main() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));

  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  var connectivityProvider = ConnectivityProvider();
  await connectivityProvider.startMonitoring();
  await NotificationController.getInitialNotificationAction();
  await initializeLocalNotifications(debug: true);
  await initializeRemoteNotifications(debug: true);
  //addFirebaseMessagingListener();

  runApp(MyApp(connectivityProvider: connectivityProvider));
}

Future<void> initializeLocalNotifications({required bool debug}) async {
  await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      'resource://drawable/logo',
      [
        NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'alerts',
            channelName: 'Chat',
            channelDescription: 'per messaggi',
            playSound: true,
            importance: NotificationImportance.High,
            defaultColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            ledColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            icon: 'resource://drawable/logo')
      ],
      debug: debug);

  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.max,
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  // Get initial notification action is optional
  ReceivedAction? initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
      .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
}
```

i changed also AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
 android:value="high_importance_channel" />
```

what is the problem?
thanks!

Comment: is it consistently 2 minutes? because sometimes the network issue cause the delay from Firebase

Comment: yes but my network is ok and i don't know why there is delay